# Separate lists of format M=[(a,x), (b,y)] into M1=[a,b] and M2=[x,y]

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

I have a list M below which came from an external file (This is  a large list in reality, `len(M)>10000`).

> M=[(1, 100), (2, 200), (3, 300), (4, 400)]

However, I want to separate it into `M1=[1,2,3,4]` and `M2=[100,200,300,400]`.
Here is how I do it at the moment,

> ```
> M1 = [] 
> M2 = [] 
> for M1,M2 in M:
>   M1.append(M1) 
>   M2.append(M2)
> ```

I was wondering if there is a simpler and more efficient way to do it, a solution that uses built-in functions in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do it:

```
M1, M2 = zip(*M)
```

M1 and M2 will be tuples. You can transform them into lists if you want:

```
M1, M2 = map(list, zip(*M))
```

or with a genexp:

```
M1, M2 = (list(i) for i in zip(*M))
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution, more efficient than yours because it uses implicit loops is:

```
>>> [m1 for m1, _ in M]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [m2 for _, m2 in M]
>>> [100, 200, 300, 400]
```

But better is using the `*` operator and `zip`:

```
>>> M1, M2 = zip(*M)
>>> M1
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> M2
(100, 200, 300, 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
M1, M2 = zip(*M)
```

That works for tuples as well as lists.

If you really have a long external file though, your initial version might be faster, as this approach will send 10k arguments to zip, and hence keep all the content in memory.